# css div max-width not working

Tags: css, html

I think it's my lack of css knowledge, but i don't get this thing working. My purpose is to have a container div which have the MAXIUMUM witdh of 800px and aligned in the middle of the page, with one or two elements per 'row', depending on the available screen-space. But in the example you see that the whole 800px is taken. How to accomplish that the 800px is only the max?

HTML:

```
<div style="background-color:red;max-width:800px;display: inline-block">
  <div class="contentgedeelte">
    <h2>nieuws</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="contentgedeelte">
    <h2>nieuws</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="contentgedeelte">
    <h2>nieuws</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="contentgedeelte">
    <h2>nieuws</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contentgedeelte {
  width:310px;
  background:white;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/plunje/LmJSy/

Comment: It's just the way DIV behaves. If you give it `display: inline-block`, it will not stretch to max width by default.

Comment: I see it working correctly.  800px is only the maximum width.  If you see differently, please state which browser you are using.

Comment: Seemed to work fine for me, it will only be smaller than 800 if your viewport is smaller than 800 px

Answer (score 3):

OK, [here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/LmJSy/14/):

```
#container {
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.row { 
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.contentgedeelte {
    width:310px;
    background:white;
    margin:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

You'll need to add a `.row` element to wrap your `contentgedeelte`s in pairs (if that's how you want them displayed). To be honest you're better off just calculating the widths properly, but if you really can't, try this. Also, I've taken your container element, remove the inline styling and added the ID `#container`.

Comment: thanx for your suggestion, but it's not exactly what i'm looking for, i made my purpose clearer (i hope).

Answer (score 1):

Use display: block; instead of inline.

Inline-block is for elements which line up side by side, not for pagewraps. If this is a center of the page container there is no need to display inline.

If you want the articles to display as inline elements, that seems to work.

Or just tally your styles to add up to 400px instead of 340px.

Answer (score 0):

You need a little more structure. See below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="contentgedeelte">
            <h2>nieuws</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="contentgedeelte">
            <h2>nieuws</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="contentgedeelte">
            <h2>nieuws</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="contentgedeelte">
            <h2>nieuws</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    max-width: 800px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.contentgedeelte {
    width:48%;
    background:white;
    margin:1%;
    float:left;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;
    display: block;
}
```